# Altmodische Rechtschreibungen mit "e" am Ende

Tags: grammatical-case, dative, quotes

Ich habe eine sehr pedantische Frage, die um einen einzigen Buchstaben geht, die ich trotzdem stellen wollte.

Ich lese momentan das 1922 veröffentlichte Buch *Siddhartha* von Hermann Hesse und habe eine Frage zur Rechtschreibung von Wörtern und wie man sich damals entschieden hat, welche Rechtschreibung für ein bestimmtes Wort richtig war. Hier ist ein Zitat aus dem Buch:

> ... Vasudeva stand am **Herd** und kochte Reis. Siddhartha warf ihm einen Blick zu, den er lächelnd erwiderte.
>
> "Sie wird sterben," sagte Siddhartha leise.
>
> Vasudeva nickte, über sein freundliches Gesicht lief der Feuerschein vom **Herde.**

Warum hat Hesse "Herd" und "Herde" geschrieben?  Gibt es einen grammatischen Grund, warum man sich damals dafür entschieden hätte, "Hemd" statt "Hemde" zu schreiben, oder hat das einfach nur mit dem für einen Nichtmuttersprachler wie mich allzu subtilen Sprachgefühl zu tun?

Ich weiß, dass viele dieser Rechtschreibungen von Wörtern mit "e" am Ende altmodisch/veraltet sind, und ich habe viele solche Wörter im Buch gelesen (z.B. Manne, Freunde, Diebe,...), die nicht mehr mit "e" am Ende geschrieben werden.  Wann ungefähr hat das sich geändert?

Comment: Wer das sprachgeschichtlich tackeln will: https://silo.tips/downloadFile/ein-dativ-e-wie-es-im-buche-steht

Comment: @starrin: 1. Bitte keine Antworten als Kommentar posten, auch keine Antwortfragmente. 2. Bitte keine Link-only-Antworten posten. Die meisten Links sterben bevor stackexchange stirbt, und in 15 Jahren wir man nicht mehr wissen, dass du mit deinem Antwort-Kommentar sagen wolltest.

Comment: Das ist als Hilfestellung gedacht und will keine Antwort sein.

Comment: @starrin: Was du dir beim Schreiben denkst, kann beim Lesen niemand wissen. Was auch immer deine Intention war, es wäre besser die relevanten Informationen aus der verlinkten Seite zu extrahieren und in eine ordentliche Antwort zu verpacken.

Comment: Das ist keine Frage von Rechtschreibung, sondern Sprachwandel in Bezug auf die Inflektion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In beiden Fällen steht das Wort im Dativ singular, und viele Wörter hatten früher im Dativ singular die Endung *-e*, die heute als veraltend, in den meisten Fällen sogar als veraltet gilt. Das betrifft alle stark gebeugten Substantive, also alle männlichen und sächlichen Substantive, die im Genitiv singular die Endung *-es* oder *-s* bekommen.

Im Mittelhochdeutschen (ganz grob gesagt vor ca. 1500) hatten all diese Wörter noch ein *-e* im Dativ singular, und im geschriebenen Deutsch war das auch noch bis weit ins 20. Jahrhundert hinein üblich. Allerdings begann dieses Dativ-e schon mit dem Aufkommen der frühneuhochdeutschen Sprache zu verschwinden, also vor rund 500 Jahren. (Der Beginn des Frühneuhochdeutschen wird auf 1350 bis 1650 datiert, das geschah also nicht über Nacht.)

In den ostmitteldeutschen Dialekten wird diese Endung auch auch heute noch standardmäßig verwendet. Un din einigen Wendungen ist diese Endung auch heute sogar im Standarddeutsch noch immer die einzige Variante, oder zumindest die deutlich häufigere:

- Das Haus; vor dem Haus; ich bin zu Haus**e**
- Das Jahr; vor dem Jahr 1846; im Jahr**e** 1846
- Der Hof; im Hof steht eine Linde; am Hof**e** König Ludwigs
- Der Tod; sie hat Angst vor dem Tod; er hat sie zu Tod**e** erschreckt
- Der Grund; er macht das ohne erkennbaren Grund; im Grund**e** genommen
- Das Buch; so steht es in dem Buch; wie es im Buch**e** steht

Dieses Dativ-e kann man auch heute noch verwenden, es ist eine ganz korrekte Variante, vor allem, wenn man eine gehobene (manchmal eher überhebliche) Ausdrucksweise verwendet.

Dass Hesse beide Formen abwechselnd verwendet hat, ist also nicht sonderlich ungewöhnlich. Das Buch Siddhartha ist ziemlich genau 100 Jahre alt (geschrieben 1919 bis 1922, erschienen 1922), es erschien also in einer Zeit als das Dativ-e noch allgemeiner Standard im geschriebenen Deutsch war, im gesprochenen Deutsch aber schon vielfach verschwunden war.

Comment: Das vernachlässigt erstens die Textkritik - vor der Zäsur (Sie wird sterben) -vs- danach, zweitens Hesses Stil und Gewöhnung und drittens den Unterschied zwischen Position am und Bewegung vom Herd; ich finde das eminent wichtig für die Frage, 'warum Hesse das so schreibt'.

Comment: Ein expliziter Hinweis, dass das abschließende -e keine Frage der *Rechtschreibung* ist, sondern eher der üblichen Grammatikregeln bzw. des Vokabulars, wäre für den Fragesteller eventuell hilfreich.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Nicht nur das, es ist auch eine *Stilfrage* und eine *Frage der Phrasen*.

Comment: An alle drei Kommentatoren: Was hindert euch daran bessere Antworten zu schreiben, anstatt an der einzigen existierenden Antwort herumzunörgeln?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich habe nichts moniert, ich habe eine Ergänzung empfohlen. Ich sehe nicht, wie ich eine bessere Antwort schreiben sollte - diese hier kopieren, um dann meinen einen Ergänzungssatz hinzuzufügen? Das ist wohl kaum Sinn der Sache. Diese Antwort *ist ja bereits* sehr gut, wie ich finde; ich halte nur die eine zusätzliche Klarstellung für hilfreich gegenüber dem Fragesteller. Belasse ich sie in einem Kommentar, wird sie eventuell irgendwann gelöscht (da Kommentare auf SE ja nur ggf. vorübergehende Anmerkungen sein sollen), also empfehle ich die Aufnahme in das, was wohl ...

Comment: ... ohnehin die umfassendste Antwort werden wird. Die Alternative wäre, die Aussage direkt in die Antwort hineinzueditieren, aber das empfinde ich i.A. als unhöflich gegenüber dem Antwortschreiber, dem ich gerne die "kreative Kontrolle" über seine/ihre Antwort überlasse. Es tut mir leid, wenn der Weg, die Ergänzung statt dessen im Kommentar vorzuschlagen, als Beschwerde rüberkam.

Answer (score 2):

Interessant an dieser Beobachtung ist, dass Hesse das Dativ-e manchmal verwendet hat und manchmal nicht (was, wie Schölnast dargestellt hat, beides grammatisch korrekt ist). Die Frage ist also, wie es zu dieser Variation kommt. Es könnte euphonische Gründe haben. Was die beiden Fälle unterscheidet, ist der lautliche Kontext. Im ersten Fall folgt innerhalb eines engen Satzgefüges die vokalisch anlautende Konjunktion *und.* Im zweiten Fall hingegen steht das Wort am Satzende.

Es könnte sein, dass die Folge von auslautendem Schwa und vokalischem Anlaut im nächsten Wort («stand am Herd**e‿u**nd») von Hesse als ungünstig empfunden wurde. Dies würde insbesondere dann plausibel, falls wir für Hesse eine Aussprache ohne Glottisschlag annehmen könnten – was mich angesichts seiner württembergischen Herkunft und Verbindungen in die Schweiz nicht unwahrscheinlich dünkt. Bei einer Aussprache ohne Glottisschlag würde nämlich zwischen dem Schwa und dem folgenden *u* ein Hiat entstehen, also dass Aufeinanderstossen von zwei Vokalen in zwei verschiedenen Silben ohne irgendeinen konsonantischen trennenden Laut, was in vielen Sprachen als ungünstig empfunden wird. Das Auslassen des Dativ-e («stand am Her**d‿u**nd») vermeidet den Hiat.

Die Euphonie-Hypothese liesse sich also folgendermassen formulieren:

1. Grundsätzlich hat Hesse das Dativ-e bevorzugt.
2. Ausser in Hiat-Position.

Als Nächstes müsste man nun in Hesses Texten nachzählen, ob diese Euphonie-Hypothese standhält oder nicht.